# Remove base path from file path

Tags: vb.net

I am retrieving multiple files using an OpenFileDialog, and would like to remove the base folder from the path.

If my user Selects photos from a folder (Example : c:\user\Username\Pictures\Holiday\Beach), I would like to remove the "C:\users\Username\Pictures\" part from the filename, so that I am left with "Holiday\Beach\Photo.jpg" for every file selected.

EDIT :

I was hoping for something similar to [this](http://pastebin.com/9eQEjqv5), but the FolderBrowser can't select files as well.

Comment: Look at the Path class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx It has methods to get file names, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "base folder". Do you mean everything except that last directory in the path plus the filename. In other words if the patch is "C:\d1\d2\d3\d4\d5\d6\filename.ext", you want to keep "d6\filename.ext"?

Comment: @Blackwood see my edit. I forgot to add that part

Comment: So you want the filename after its folder after its folder i.e. folder1\folder2\filename. What they select files in `C:\users\User\Documents\ `? You get `User\Documents\filename`, correct?

Comment: @Verdolino Something like that yes :)

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. Are you saying you want to remove the drive letter and the first three directories in the path? What if there are less than three directories in the path (e.g. D:\Test\Info.txt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .NET Directory class:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
        ofd.Multiselect = True
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            For Each fileName In ofd.FileNames
                MessageBox.Show(getFileWithParents(fileName, 2))
            Next fileName
        End If
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function getFileWithParents(filename As String, numberOfParents As Integer) As String
    Dim directories As New List(Of String)()
    Dim newFilename = filename
    Dim hasParent As Boolean = Directory.GetParent(newFilename) IsNot Nothing
    While hasParent
        Dim dir = Directory.GetParent(newFilename).ToString()
        directories.Add(dir)
        newFilename = dir
        hasParent = Directory.GetParent(newFilename) IsNot Nothing
    End While
    If directories.Count <= numberOfParents Then
        Return filename
    Else
        Return filename.Replace(directories(numberOfParents), "")
    End If
End Function
```

This allows you to specify how many parent directories to return, and accounts for when the user is selecting files from a directory with less than specified number of parents.

Comment: I'm guessing there is no persistent way to do this. This the code I use with FolderBrowserDialog to remove the base path : http://pastebin.com/7aaYCJ1V. I wish there was a similar for the OpenFileDialog

Comment: @Adriaan Sorry, I hadn't tested it before posting. Now it's tested and working. Replace `MessageBox.Show(result)` with what you want to do with string result.

Comment: This one works, but like you said it only retrieves 2 parent folders :)

Comment: @Adriaan Still not clear then. `c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\file.txt` >> `\folder3\folder4\file.txt` and `c:\folder1\folder2\file.txt` >> `\folder1\folder2\file.txt`. So it always returns the file with its two nearest parents. It can be reworked to return a different number by using `.Parent` a different number of times.

Comment: I understand that, but I can't detect how many parents there are. That depends on the user's file system. Maybe I should just create a custom filebrowser dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `Substring()`

```vb
basePath = OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory
If basePath = "" Then
    basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
End If

If path.StartsWith(basePath) Then
    path = path.Substring(basePath.Length + 1)
End If
```

Note: `+ 1` is for length of path separator.

This approach has its limitations, for example what if your base path contains slashes `/` as separators (which are valid in Windows) or what if it is UNC path. Easiest way around is to ensure that your base path has always format compatible with path returned from file dialog.

Actually, I have solution which makes this task trivial by splitting the path into components, its also correctly handling both `/` and `\`, it is also handling absolute and relative paths, standard paths and UNC paths, but it has 1000+ lines as a library. I'm not ready to share it. I wanted to say you either have to deal with this in complex way (like I mentioned) or just use some simple limited "solution", as I wrote in first part of the answer.

Comment: This is the method I use with the FolderBrowser dialog, but how would this work with OpenFileDialog? How would I retrieve the BasePath?

Comment: openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory as basepath?

Comment: @Adriaan – by *base folder* do you mean the folder at which the dialog opens? Because normally, there is nothing like base folder. Its on you to have it stored somewhere. My solution assumes that you have `basePath` configured somewhere.

Comment: To clarify a bit more, Say my user select multiple files from a path, say C:\Users\User\Pictures\Holiday\SomePlace, I want to remove the c:\Users\User\Pictures part so that I only have Holiday\SomePlace\Photo.png

Comment: @Adriaan – I understand that very well. The problem is that you need to have `C:\Users\User\Pictures` stored somewhere in the application. System dialog has this value stored – it is one per application – but it is in the Registry. It updates whenever user accepts the dialog. Do you actually want to know how to read it from there?

Comment: I could try that yes :)

Comment: Yes, but it is quite different question. In this question you were only asking how to remove known prefix ("base path") from full path. Obtaining that "base path" for given application is another type of problem. Maybe you can post separate question for it (and try some search before.).   Another viable solution is to start with base path `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`. Will this be acceptable for you?

Comment: @Adriaan – check now. Maybe `InitialDirectory` property will contain "base path".

Comment: That would work if I knew that the user was selecting the files from their documents folder each time :) InitialDirectory return blank?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90464/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-adriaan).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a novel approach since it does not actually perform a string replace, but should work just fine.

```
Function RemoveRoot(ByVal root As String, ByVal target As String) As String
    'format the paths first
    Dim p As String = String.Join("\", (From t In target.Split(("\").ToCharArray()) Where t <> "" Select t).ToArray())
    Dim r As String = String.Join("\", (From t In root.Split(("\").ToCharArray()) Where t <> "" Select t).ToArray())
    If p.StartsWith(r) Then Return p.Remove(0, r.Length)
    Return target
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long discussion, it seems that the best way to do this is via a custom control. Thanks to everyone for the help